# Change default interface docker container

Tags: networking, docker, nat

I'm struggling with this problem for two days.

Assumptions:

- Docker network (and interface) named **docknet** type **bridge** subnet **172.18.0.0/16**
- Two interfaces **eth0** (192.168.1.1) and **eth1** (192.168.2.1)
- Default routing goes through **eth0**

What I want:

- Outgoing traffic from container attached to **docknet** must go to **eth1**

What I tried:

- Default iptable rule created by docker left untouched:

`-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o docknet -j MASQUERADE`

- My rules:

`iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 -j MARK --set-mark 1`

`ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table 2`

Where table 2 is:

`default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1 proto static`

With this setup when I try to ping 8.8.8.8 from a container (172.18.0.2) attached to docknet the following happens:

- 172.18.0.2 gets translated to 192.168.2.1
- the packet goes through eth1
- the packet returns to eth1 with src addr 8.8.8.8 and dst 192.168.2.1

from here a reverse translation from 192.168.2.1 to 172.168.0.2 should happen but running `tcpdump -i any host 8.8.8.8` there is not trace about this translation

I checked out also conntrack -L and this is the result:

> icmp     1 29 src=172.18.0.2 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=9 src=8.8.8.8 dst=192.168.2.1 type=0 code=0 id=9 mark=0 use=1

Useful info:

- eth1 is actually a 4G usb dongle
- ip forwarding is active
- `curl --interface eth1 ipinfo.io` works as expected